# WePay payment gateway integration in PHP

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I want to integrate WePay payment gateway for my site. I have download SDK from www.wepay.com and integrate it as the API tutorial given in WePay, i am done till account creation and API call, but stuck in checkout page. My checkout page goes blank, i am not able to find what the actual problem is?

If anybody is familiar with WePay payment gateway then, please help me out from this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to start with trying to get a decent error message. You can check what they mean [here](https://www.wepay.com/developer/reference/errors). Use the developer tools like the network tab in Chrome, or Firebug to see how the requests are send and what errors are sending back. An API call is based on an HTTP request so is easy to monitor. It can be that the user is not good or the token or a million other things.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I got the problem, actually the problem is not concerned with API Call or WePay SDK, the main problem is with cURL. It's disabled on my server. I have enabled it and getting the API response from WePay server.